# write function to count number of vowels in a string

Tags: r

I was assigned the following homework question:

> Write a function that will take a string as input and return the number of vowels in that string as the
>   output
>
> • Name the function get_vowel_count
>   • Make sure to document what the function does using comments in R

But when I feed the function a given string, it spits out 0 vowels in the console when there are clearly vowels in the string I give (e.g. "John Doe" contains three vowels)

I've changed the `if` statement a bit to better account for vowels, but I think the program will only count if the string is exactly an "a", "e", "i", etc.

I'm not sure what syntax exists to say "contains" rather than "is equal to"

```
mystr <- "John Doe"

get_vowel_count <- function(phrase) {
  counter <- 0
  for (i in phrase) {
    if ((i == 'a') | (i == 'e') | (i == 'i') | (i == 'o') | (i == 'u')) {
      counter <- counter + 1 
    }   
  }
  output <- paste("Your phrase has", counter, "vowels in it!" )
  print(output)
}

get_vowel_count(mystr)
```

The output is displaying 0 vowels, where, the expected should say "Your phrase has 3 vowels in it!"

Comment: trying doing it in one line `your_vector %in% vowels %>% sum`

Comment: You may also want to check out `strsplit` for splitting a string into single characters. E.g. take a look at `strsplit(mystr)`.

Answer (score 4):

`for (i in phrase)` doesn't work the way you think it does (in particular, it doesn't work the way it works in Python).  In R, `phrase` is treated as a **1-element** vector containing a single character string, not (as in Python) an ordered collection of letters.

So the first time through your loop, `i` is equal to "John Doe", which is not equal to any vowel. And your loop only repeats once.

- You could use `strsplit(phrase,"")[[1]]` to split the string into a vector of letters
- Or you could use something like (`for i in seq(nchar(phrase)) ...  if (substr(phrase,i,i)==...)`
- To simplify your test of vowels you could use something like `if (substr(phrase,i,i) %in% c("a","e","i","o","u")) ...`

Answer (score 2):

I would remove all non vowels and count remaining characters :

```
nchar(gsub("[^aeiouy]","","John Doe", ignore.case = TRUE))
#> [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop `i` was just passing whole string to `if` statement and loop was running only one time. 
Now `i` is passing a single character at a time and running for the length of the string.

It is good to first convert string to lowercase to avoid case conflict.

```
mystr <- "John Doe"
mystr_lower =tolower(mystr)

get_vowel_count <- function(phrase) {
  counter <- 0
  for (i in unlist(strsplit(phrase, ""))) {
    if ( i %in% c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")) {
      counter <- counter + 1 
    }   
  }
  output <- paste("Your phrase has", counter, "vowels 
in it!" )
  print(output)
}

get_vowel_count(mystr_lower)

# Output: [1] "Your phrase has 3 vowels in it!"
```